# How to find Select all Phone number that has number 5 6 7 in 5th 6th 7th position in the number

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a way to print all the phone numbers (10 digit number) in column `Phone_num` of table `Customer` that has digit 5 6 7 in 5th 6th 7th position in the whole number, using `SELECT FROM WHERE` format.

Comment: What database server?  There are several ways to do this, but they will vary based on the flavor of SQL you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the SUBSTRING function in the WHERE clause.  Different databases have slightly different syntax, so you will need to look up the syntax of your database.

In SQL Server, you could write:

```
select phone_num from customer where substring(phone_num, 5, 3) = '567'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to find all numbers that have 567 in the 5th, 6th, and 7th position. You can do this with a regular expression:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number ~ '^[0-9]{4}567[0-9]{3}$'
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'm looking for a way has number 567 in "exact" 5th 6th 7th position, not any position in the whole number

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you want now. You want to find all numbers that have 567 in the 5th, 6th, and 7th position. You can do this with a regular expression that I will provide in my edited answer.